# How to Get Broadcast Address of (IPv4) net.IPNet?

Tags: networking, go

Is there a built-in function to calculate the broadcast address of a `net.IPNet` struct?

Comment: Maybe **[`this`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/IrfXFTUavXE)** link can help you?

Comment: I had looked at the beginning of that thread, but hadn't made it all the way through to the end where the goods are. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link @Dsafds has the answer. Here for history's sake, and so you don't have to read through the thread yourself. Code is Mikio Hara's with minor modifications made by me.

```
func lastAddr(n *net.IPNet) (net.IP, error) { // works when the n is a prefix, otherwise...
    if n.IP.To4() == nil {
        return net.IP{}, errors.New("does not support IPv6 addresses.")
    }
    ip := make(net.IP, len(n.IP.To4()))
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(ip, binary.BigEndian.Uint32(n.IP.To4())|^binary.BigEndian.Uint32(net.IP(n.Mask).To4()))
    return ip, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) library provides such functionality.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
// from a net.IPNet
_, ipNet, _ := net.ParseCIDR("1.2.3.4/16")
addr, _ := ipaddr.NewIPAddressFromNetIPNet(ipNet)
bcast, _ := addr.ToIPv4().ToBroadcastAddress()
fmt.Println("broadcast address is", bcast)
```

Output:

```
broadcast address is 1.2.255.255/16
```

```golang
// or from a string directly
addr = ipaddr.NewIPAddressString("1.2.3.4/16").GetAddress()
bcast, _ = addr.ToIPv4().ToBroadcastAddress()
fmt.Println("broadcast address is", bcast)
```

Output:

```
broadcast address is 1.2.255.255/16
```